# Splunk graph data grouped by "release" and "time"

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I need to create a graph that will have date on the x axis and "successfully_processed" and "failed_to_process" on y axis group by "release".

This is my example:

```
|makeresults
| eval raw="100, 2, typeA, 2022-05-25T19:53:51.000-07:00|110, 3, typeA, 2022-05-26T19:53:51.000-08:00|150, 1, typeB, 2022-05-25T19:53:51.000-08:00"
| makemv raw delim="::"
| mvexpand raw
| fields - _time
| streamstats count AS _serial
| makemv raw delim="|"
| mvexpand raw
| rex field=raw "^(?<success>[^,]+),(?<fail>[^,]+),(?<release>[^,]+),(?<_time>[^,]+)$"
| fields - raw
| stats values(success) as Successfully_processed  values(fail) as Failed_to_process by release
```

When I group them by release I can't figure out how to get the date as well. I need every log "successfully_processed" and "failed_to_process" to be shown per day grouped by "release".

Can anyone help please? Thank you

Comment: Is this want you want?
`| bin _time span=1d
| stats values(success) as Successfully_processed  values(fail) as Failed_to_process by release _time`

Comment: This is using "release" on x axis instead of _time and it's not showing the Failed ones for some reason

Comment: Failed is not showing as they are string not number.

change seconds line to this
 `| eval raw="10,2, typeA, 2022-05-25T19:53:51.000-07:00|11,3, typeA, 2022-05-26T19:53:51.000-08:00|15,1, typeB, 2022-05-25T19:53:51.000-08:00"`

and with your real data make sure they are numbers.

Use Rich G's answer but also make sure that _time field is in unix time for the bin command to work properly.

https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SCS/current/SearchReference/DateandTimeFunctions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `chart` command.

```
| makeresults
| eval raw="100, 2, typeA, 2022-05-25T19:53:51.000-07:00|110, 3, typeA, 2022-05-26T19:53:51.000-08:00|150, 1, typeB, 2022-05-25T19:53:51.000-08:00"
| makemv raw delim="::"
| mvexpand raw
| streamstats count AS _serial
| makemv raw delim="|"
| mvexpand raw
| rex field=raw "^(?<success>[^,]+),(?<failure>[^,]+),(?<release>[^,]+),(?<_time>[^,]+)$"
| fields - raw
| chart values(success) as success, values(failure) as failure over _time by release
```

Comment: This looks better but I'm still not seeing the "fail" numbers in the graph. I thought that's because the value is too small but when I try to split the graphs using Threllis layout it still doesn't show up and I don't understand why. did you manage to create a graph and see the fail and success?

Comment: This works, Dragan your example data is just not great,
Fail is string and not a number, Also the _time field is non standard.

Comment: The failure data is not graphed because of a field name mis-match between the `rex` and `stats`/`chart` commands.  Also, don't throw away the _time field if you want to graph by date.  See my updated answer.